# update dataframe with series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

having a dataframe, I want to update subset of columns with a series of same length as number of columns being updated:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(6, 2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
>>> df

   col1  col2
0     1     0
1     2     4
2     4     4
3     4     0
4     0     0
5     3     1

>>> df.loc[:,['col1','col2']] = pd.Series([0,1])
...
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (6,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,6)
```

it fails, however, I am able to do the same thing using list:

```
>>> df.loc[:,['col1','col2']] = list(pd.Series([0,1]))
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     0     1
1     0     1
2     0     1
3     0     1
4     0     1
5     0     1
```

could you please help me to understand, why updating with series fails? do I have to perform some particular reshaping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When assigning with a pandas object, pandas treats the assignment more "rigorously".  A pandas to pandas assignment must pass stricter protocols.  Only when you turn it to a list (or equivalently `pd.Series([0, 1]).values`) did pandas give in and allow you to assign in the way you'd imagine it should work.

That higher standard of assignment requires that the indices line up as well, so even if you had the right shape, it still wouldn't have worked without the correct indices.

```
df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']] = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1] for _ in range(6)])
df
```

[image]

```
df.loc[:, ['col1', 'col2']] = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1] for _ in range(6)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! when you say "pandas give in", does that mean, that such assignment is not recommended in general? is there any better, "safer" way?

Comment: @kekert No!  Not at all.  I was being too loose with words.  when assigning with a list, pandas is assuming you know what you're doing.  It is a tremendously useful thing to be able to do.

Comment: Maybe there is some check, becuse if there are only 2 rows, it works nice - `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,(2, 2)), columns=['col1','col2'])`, `df.loc[:,['col1','col2']] =  pd.Series([0,1])` +1

Comment: Beware!!! If the rhs of your assign doesn't have the indexes in the lhs, these rows are set to null (for those columns). This is *assigning* those columns, not *updating* them.